# Importing Photos from Lion to Yosemite Photo Library to External Storage Device

Tags: macos, photos, upgrade, external-disk, file-transfer

I recently upgraded to Yosemite.  Before that, I used to have my library stored on my external hard drive.

Now I am panicking because while I was able to move my Yosemite Photo library to my external storage device, I do not know how to merge the old and the new library.  It's simply not importing.

Please help! and let me know what other information I need to provide you with.

I have a MacBook Air 10.104 OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Does the new Yosemite Photo library have anything in it?

Answer (score 1):

From [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204655):

> ### To migrate another photo library manually:
>
> 1. Quit Photos.
> 2. Hold down the Option key and open Photos.
> 3. Select the library you want to open.
> 4. If the library you want isn’t listed, click Other Library. Navigate to the library you want and click Open.
>
> You can also drag the library you’d like to open to the Photos icon in the Dock. Or you can click Create New to create an all-new, empty library.
>
> Photos can use libraries from iPhoto 8.0 or later and any version of Aperture. If you’d like to migrate a library from iPhoto 7 or earlier, use Apple’s free iPhoto Library Upgrader tool to prepare your library first.

Comment: I tried the Options key/ Open Photos/ finding the old library. This did not work. I tried dragging the library over the iPhoto icon, which also did not work.  I downloaded the iPhoto Library Upgrader, but I got the message that there was nothing to import.  Are there any other options? I am thinking of scheduling an appointment at the Genius Bar.

Comment: 1. Where is your old iPhoto library now? 2. Is there anything in the new photo library on the external drive? 3. Photos will only find the old library on option+click open Photos.app if it is available somewhere on the internal or external disk. 4. Other option is to drag the old iPhoto library to the new Photos.app, not iPhoto as you say you did. The upgraded is only needed if your iPhoto version is less than 8.0

Comment: I went to the Genius bar and they helped me out. It was kind of by chance how they figured it out. It was a bizarre case, and both technicians had no idea what was going on, but the good thing is that it worked.  The one thing I had to do is to click on the actual pictures and select them all rather than to just click on the folder.  Who knew that it was that simple!?!

Comment: In any case, I am glad I went to the Genius Bar because they were so generous and helpful. They helped me fix so many other annoying things like the calendars and my contacts and other supposedly minor but annoyingly challenging things.  I know I am gushing about them but I am so relieved that these minor annoyances disappeared and that my pictures are all safe and sound!

Comment: James, to respond to your question--the old library was empty! However, when I tried to import the pictures into the new library, we could see the thumbnails, but we could not find where the pictures are stored.  The technician just ended up clicking on the first picture and tried importing it, which worked, but it was really a puzzling case.  I had a number of such bugs -- something that should take 5 seconds to be done, but it actually was quite a puzzle. Thanks for trying to help as well!

Comment: Good to hear they could help you and solved other issues too! Keep coming if you need more help.

Comment: Jaime, I will use this forum in the future too.  I just wanted to add one more thing because I am not sure how it came across in my posts above: the guys who helped me were extremely well qualified and experienced! They were indeed geniuses!  The good feeling has not worn off!  In fact, I am off to do my happy dance again ;)